# Compatibility issues replacing generic collections with guava

Tags: java, guava, generic-collections

I am trying to update from collections generic to guava.
Inside a class I have the following structure.

```java
public NetViewerVertexShapeFactory(Integer size) {
    this(Functions.constant(size), Functions.constant(1.0F));
    /*this(new ConstantTransformer(size), new ConstantTransformer(1.0F));*/
    this.size = size;
}

public NetViewerVertexShapeFactory(Function<NetViewerNode, Integer> vsf, Function<NetViewerNode, Float> varf) {
    this.vsf = vsf;
    this.varf = varf;
}
```

As someone very new to java and to this code, I am trying to go by documentation of the libraries.
According to these, second line and the line commented out below should be equivalent, returning a function that provides only the given constant. However, 
NetBeans is giving me an Error, where the function given by `Functions.constant` does not comply with the function type required below, which I absolutely get, but why was it different with `ConstantTransformer`?
How can I solve this?

Comment: try `this.vsf = vsf::apply`

Comment: They may implement _different_ `Function` interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, it's much simpler (and briefer) to use lambdas. So:

```
this(unused -> size, unused -> 1.0F);
```